# Get X/Y point of the actual form in VB6

Tags: vb6

Simple question, but could somehow not find any answer on google

Try to get form position from xy but i cant in vb6. any solution for vb6?

Comment: What do the (Me) `.Top` and `.Left` properties report?

Answer (score 1):

To find y, use `Me.Top`

To find x, use `Me.Left`

Example:

```
Dim Y As Single
Dim X As Single
Y = Me.Top
X = Me.Left
```